# ejabberd mod_archive_odbc performance

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 2.1.12 with mod_archive_odbc configured for mysql database. I checked logs while saving single message and they look terrifying. Ejabberd suppose to be highly scalable xmpp server but with this module enabled probably mysql database will be bottle neck.

Logs:

```
7 Query begin
7 Query select * from archive_global_prefs where us = '6@my.server'
7 Query select * from archive_jid_prefs where us = '6@my.server' and with_user = '4' and with_server = 'my.server' and with_resource = ''
7 Query select * from archive_jid_prefs where us = '6@my.server' and with_user = '4' and with_server = 'my.server' and with_resource = ''
7 Query select * from archive_jid_prefs where us = '6@my.server' and with_user = '' and with_server = 'my.server' and with_resource = ''
7 Query commit
5 Query begin
5 Query update archive_collections set with_resource = '', change_by = '6@my.server/my-resource', change_utc = '2013-05-11 09:47:46', subject = '', thread = '' where id = 9
5 Query insert into archive_messages(coll_id, utc, dir, name, body) values(9, '2013-05-11 09:47:46', 1, '', 'some random message')
5 Query commit
5 Query begin
5 Query select * from archive_global_prefs where us = '4@my.server'
5 Query select * from archive_jid_prefs where us = '4@my.server' and with_user = '6' and with_server = 'my.server' and with_resource = 'my-resource'
5 Query select * from archive_jid_prefs where us = '4@my.server' and with_user = '6' and with_server = 'my.server' and with_resource = ''
5 Query select * from archive_jid_prefs where us = '4@my.server' and with_user = '' and with_server = 'my.server' and with_resource = ''
5 Query commit
3 Query begin
3 Query update archive_collections set with_resource = 'my-resource', change_by = '4@my.server', change_utc = '2013-05-11 09:47:46', subject = '', thread = '' where id = 10
3 Query insert into archive_messages(coll_id, utc, dir, name, body) values(10, '2013-05-11 09:47:46', 0, '', 'some random message')
3 Query commit
```

This gives us 8 selects, 2 updates and 2 inserts for every message. I looked into [plugin's code](https://github.com/ptevans/ejabberd-modules/blob/master/mod_archive/trunk/src/mod_archive_odbc.erl) and found out that there is [multiple insert implementation](https://github.com/ptevans/ejabberd-modules/blob/master/mod_archive/trunk/src/mod_archive_odbc.erl#L1347), but this is only for manual archiving.

Is there some way to optimise this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Erlang VM is highly scalable and reliable. eJabberd is not.

Don't be scared of modification of the mod archive. Also you can look into optimizing ejabberd odbc modules, they perform way too many transactions.

Comment: Hey, I thought that there is easy way to change this, but I realized I am not using xep 136 (only connect to ejabberd db with other app) so I just wrote my simple archive plugin which does one insert but not enables xep 136. It was easier then I expected, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

XMPP archive is now structured around [XEP-0313 Message Archive Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html). It is supported as a default since [ejabberd 15.06](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-15-06/), with several backends and should scale to your need.

By switching to MAM implementation, you will be more future proof as all modern XMPP clients are taking that specification as a reference for implementing archiving.